# NUnit - Equal(this, that), True(this == that) or That (this, Is.EqualTo(that))?

Tags: c#, nunit

Our house framework uses a generic class, `DBField<T>`, to emulate entity fields with databases that aren't compatible with Entity Framework (like, Oracle 11 or Sybase).

We're trying to make it as transparent as possible (again, like entity fields) so that the following code works:

```
    DBField<int?> z_intLength = 2;
    while (z_intLength <= 5)
    {
        z_intLength++;
    }

    //[...]

    DBField<int?> z_intMaxLength = 10;
    if (z_intLength > z_intMaxLength)
    {
    }
```

The above works nicely. We've used `public static implicit operator DBField<T>(T value)` and `public static implicit operator T(DBField<T> value)`, along with overriding `==` and the other comparison operators, as well as implementing `IEquatable<DBField<T>>`, `IComparable`, and `IComparable<DBField<T>>`.

Now we're trying to put `DBField<T>` through NUnit tests, in which we're rather new.

Notably, we're trying our hand with various equivalents:

```
            string z_strComment = "Comment";
            _objOrder2.OrderComment = z_strComment;

            //[...]

            Assert.True("Comment" == _objOrder2.OrderComment);
            Assert.That("Comment", Is.EqualTo(_objOrder2.OrderComment));
            Assert.That(_objOrder2.OrderComment, Is.EqualTo("Comment"));
            Assert.Equals("Comment", _objOrder2.OrderComment);
```

The first two assertions pass and the next two fail.

1. There seems to be a difference in the inner workings of each assertion. Can someone explain what it is?
2. More precisely, debugging with breakpoints seems to indicate that `Assert.That("Comment", Is.EqualTo(_objOrder2.OrderComment))` tests `_objOrder2.OrderComment.Equals("Comment")`; I'd expect it the other way around. Am I missing something?
3. I understand that `True()` and `Equals()` are older than `That()`. Which ones are preferable in which situations?

Comment: `Is.EqualTo` and `Equals` checks for object type as well instead of just logic condition behind it. So it make sense that your custom object property is not equal to System.String since it's different type.

Comment: Assert.AreEqual(_objOrder2.OrderComment, "Comments"); You can use AreEqual  instead of Equals try this once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 things at play here:

1. How useful the error message from NUnit is if the test fails
2. What style of NUnit API you're using

---

```
Assert.True("Comment" == _objOrder2.OrderComment)
```

If this test fails, you get a message like "Expected true, was false". Unhelpful, as it doesn't tell you what the value of `_objOrder2.OrderComment` actually was.

---

```
Assert.Equals("Comment", _objOrder2.OrderComment);
Assert.That(_objOrder2.OrderComment, Is.EqualTo("Comment"));
```

These two are equivalent, the first one uses a slightly shorter syntax, the second one uses a more extensible [constraint model](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/assertion-models/constraint.html) (you can write your own assertions, e.g. `Assert.That(x, new MyConstraint(y))`).

If the test fails, you'll get something like `Expected "Comment", was "Actual Value"`. That's a bit more helpful.

---

```
Assert.That("Comment", Is.EqualTo(_objOrder2.OrderComment));
```

This one's backwards. If it fails, you'll get something like `Expected "Actual Value", was "Comment"`, which is just wrong.

---

Regarding the older-style `Assert.Equals` vs the constraint model `Assert.That`, it's (annoyingly) up to personal preference. Personally I use `Assert.Equals` because I find it easier to read, but I'll use `Assert.That` over `CollectionAssert` when doing assertions on collections, and I'll also use it when writing my own assertions.

Read the comment from one of the NUnit developers below, about how they found that users found the `Assert.That` style more easily understood.

Comment: Nice answer! I'll add that the older `Assert.Equals` led to much confusion as to the proper order. It seems that putting the expected value first is only natural to devs with experience in other frameworks, which do the same thing. `Assert.That` with the actual value as the first argument was found to be more easily understood by most users because it mimics the natural language order in English as well as many European languages. Of course, most people find things natural when they are used to them. :-)

Comment: Thanks! About using `Assert.That()` backwards: we still want to do that, so we can test how `DBField<T>` plays on either side of the `==` operator. I see your point though, of course.

Comment: `Assert.That` doesn't use the `==` operator. If you're explicitly testing the `==` operator, I'd expect you to be calling `==` yourself, rather than assming that NUnit is doing what you expect.

Comment: @canton7 So we're back with `True()`, the one who lets us use `==` explicitly. Unhelpful as it can be, that's what we need here.

Comment: Yeah, in this very specific case (and you wouldn't be doing that with strings, as your question does!). But I'd heavily comment it, and add your own custom message to the assertion.

Comment: Why not with strings? (Also, duly noted about a custom message. I'll look into that. Thanks again!)

Comment: ... Because you don't need to test *string's* `==` operator.

Comment: We still need to test that `{string variable} == {DBField<string> variable}` works. I feel I'm still missing something you mean here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234572/discussion-between-canton7-and-jean-david-lanz).

Comment: @Charlie I'm confused: to me, "actual value" is the variable/property one is testing and "expected value" is the (often literal) value to compare it with. My experience in question 2 suggests that `That()` works with `Assert.That(actual_value, Is.EqualTo(expected_value))`. Your comment seems to indicate that it's the other way around. Can you please clarify for me?

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz Me too! It works just as you say. My comment says "Assert.That with the actual value as the first argument was found to be more easily understood..." ???

Comment: @Charlie Sorry, re-reading my comment it wasn't as clear as I expected. What I was referring to in question 2 was that with `Assert.That(actual_value, Is.EqualTo(expected_value))` syntax I'd have expected the inner test to be `actual_value.Equals(expected_value)`, while experience seems to suggests it is the other way around. It's the order of that inner test that confuses me. Do you have insight on it?

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz Actually, classic asserts and constraint-based asserts all use the same implementation... they are just syntax on top of the internal implementation. In fact, when constraint-based asserts were introduced, all the classic asserts were rewritten so that they actually call the constraint-based model.

As for why it uses `expected.Equals`... that's because the type of the expected value is always known to the test author, whereas that of the actual value may not be.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that NUnit has its own definition of equality, which is subtly different from both mathematical and usual programming language equality. this seems justified because of how equality assertions are used in tests. In particular, assert equality is asymmetric, both in terms of the side effects (error message, e.g.) and the actual result (e.g. two arrays are equal if the contents are the same). Unfortunately, it's a subtle point, usually not discovered until after some years of usage. :-(